# Breaking the each loop in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How will I break the loop if a particular condition is satisfied?

My input file has around n number of lines. If the required information is got at some mth line I need to break the loop instead of reading the remaining lines.

```
new File("test.txt").readLines().reverseEach{line ->
   println line

   if(line.contains("Data"))
   break;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `find` to do this. Find ends the loop the first time the closure returns `true` and returns the last found element.

This

```
(1..20).find{
    println it
    it == 5
}
```

Would be the following in the groovy console.

```
1
2
3
4
5
Result: 5
```

Comment: Using 'find' like this assumes it's implemented as a single-threaded sequential algorithm in the version/implementation of Groovy you're using.

Comment: @VorgvanGeir Ok, you have a point there. The groovy doc only states ["Finds the first item matching the IDENTITY Closure"](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find()). Just out of curiosity... are there any Groovy implementations that do this differently, e.g. multi-threaded or non-sequential?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just break from closure. You can either throw an exception and exit from it, or do not use closures at all. Read all lines in array/list and iterate through it.